# How can I calculate the sum of one column based off of the data from another column in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have three columns in Excel: child ASIN (Amazon SKU for size/color), parent ASIN (the entire Amazon product page w/ all color and size variants), and revenue (for the child ASIN).

What I want to do is find the revenue for all of the parent ASINs, which is found by summing the revenue of all of the child ASINs with the same parent. I also want to have the table rewritten to just be revenue and parent ASIN.

Here is an example the data I have now
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOweO.jpg

Here is what I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ31s.jpg

Comment: research `SUMIFS` or `SUMIF`

Comment: also some example data with expected output helps.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a pivottable

Comment: Added the example data. I tried using SUMIF but doing so won't be able to create the new table. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `=SUMIF(B:B,"AAA",C:C)` will give you exactly what you need. Pivot table sounds like the better way to go though as it will automatically update with new ASIN info.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivottable. Select a cell in your datarange. Go to the insert tab and click Pivot Table. Click OK. Then in the field list drag the [parent ASIN] field to Rows and the [ordered Revenue] field to values.

[image]

Comment: And make sure SUM is chosen.